# ConEmu text is too faint

Tags: conemu

I've just installed ConEmu for the first time on my Windows laptop (Windows 10, ConEmu 191012 Preview). But for some reason the text in all the windows is really faint. I've Googled and search Stack Overflow but I can't find anything about this. I've tried fiddling with the color setitngs in ConEmu but they don't seem to make any difference.

If I compare GitBash or Command Prompt when run in ConEmu as opposed to run independently, the text is much brighter when run independently. I'm having to close my curtains to be able to read the text on the screen! In the room the effect is more pronounced than it appears in the screenshots below, but you can see the difference.

GitBash run independently:

[image]

GitBash prompt in ConEmu:

[image]

Does anyone know what I can do to fix this?

Comment: Just try different color palette

Comment: OK, after a lot of trial and error I found that the "xterm" colour scheme (Top right burger icon | Settings | General | Select color scheme) is brighter. All the other colour schemes are faint though, it's very odd. None of them are easy to read in daylight. Maybe there's an assumption that ConEmu will only ever be used in rooms with the curtains drawn. Maybe there's something wrong with my eyes. It's a mystery.
There's one scheme I found that had a white background, which made the text easier to read but the actual text was still very faint.

Answer (score 0):

In case you ever come back to this or someone else stumbles upon this. In ConEmu go to settings -> In the left sidebar select Colors in the Features section-> click directly on the color picker box. Each of the colors for the included schemes Ive looked at seem to have their luminosity setting lowered for some reason. Increase the lum value to 100, its located right above the big 'Add to Custom Colors' button in the bottom right of the color window.[ConEmu Settings Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpn4L.jpg)